# Why I do not receive email from my PHP contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

From code below you can see I am trying to create contact which is send to XXX@gmail.com.
After filled form and click on SEND EMAIL I get message "Email sent!". That is OK. 
Why I do not receive contact form to my email xxx@gmail.com?

```
 <?php
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
        {
        ?>
        <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        Your name:<br>
        <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Your email:<br>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Your message:<br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
        </form>
        <?php
        } 
    else                /* send the submitted data */
        {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
            {
            echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
            }
        else{        
            $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
            $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
            mail("XXX@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
            echo "Email sent!";
            }
        }  
    ?>
```

Comment: Clue: Take a long look at `$from` ;-)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you will see the error(s).

Comment: I see where is error but I dnot know how to fix it (thanks to your line of code)

Comment: You're welcome. The answer is inside the link as a duplicate. If you haven't figured it out in 15 mins. I'll give you the answer. The reason is simple; I want you to learn and not spoonfeed you. That's why the question was closed; the variable i undefined. Go over that link and compare it with yours as to why it's doing that, using Gmail's server as the `From:`.

Comment: ..and the manual of course http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php which I'm sure is inside the duplicate link.

Comment: thanks for help and I agree that the best way is to solve it by your self. I put the question here because of lack of time :/  so this reading I will do after office time

Comment: It should be   `$from='From: $name <$email>' . "\r\n" .
    'Return-path: $email";` FYI its good to be on white list on your server too.

Comment: yes the same day, but I got "banned" here (can not ask other questins) so I have to rias my reputation :D